# Format pubDate RSS

Tags: c#

Good afternoon. I decided to get the news from a certain topic of the forum, which was not difficult. But the question arose how to change the pubDate property to a 24-hour format. At the moment, each topic has the form 12/3/2017 2:57:55 PM. And I would like to 12/3/2017 14:57:55. Or you can do it at all on 03/12/2017. Help please correct the code. Thank you!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using Classes;

namespace controls
{
    public partial class News : System.Web.UI.UserControl
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.PopulateRssFeed();
        }

        private void PopulateRssFeed()
        {
            string RssFeedUrl = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RssFeedUrl"];
            string RssMaxNews = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RssMaxNews"];

            List<Feeds> feeds = new List<Feeds>();
            try
            {
                XDocument xDoc = new XDocument();
                xDoc = XDocument.Load(RssFeedUrl);
                var items = (from x in xDoc.Descendants("item")
                             select new
                             {
                                 title = x.Element("title").Value,
                                 link = x.Element("link").Value,
                                 pubDate = x.Element("pubDate").Value,
                                 description = x.Element("description").Value,
                             }).Take(10).ToList();
                if (items != null)
                {
                    foreach (var i in items)
                    {
                        Feeds f = new Feeds
                        {
                            Title = i.title,
                            Link = i.link,
                            PublishDate = i.pubDate,
                            Description = i.description
                        };

                        feeds.Add(f);
                    }
                }

                gvRss.DataSource = feeds;
                gvRss.DataBind();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the datatype of your PublishDate property in the Feeds class? And why don't you write _select new Feeds_ instead of using an anonymous enumerable (this will avoid the foreach loop) ?

Comment: public string PublishDate { get; set; } I am just learning. Therefore, I can not say which is better and easier)

Comment: Store always a datetime value in a variable (or property) of type DateTime. This will force you to convert that XML value to a datetime. But then you can display the property in whatever format you need.

Comment: Bad while I understand you without an example. But I'll try to figure it out)